# Azure pipeline runs forever if not using approval timeout

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-yaml-pipelines

I have recently moved from Classic release to YAML release pipeline. With Classic release I would simply trigger manually the deployment I was interested in (Dev, Integration, UAT or Production).

However with YAML pipeline I use stages and they are triggered automatically after building. To prevent that, I've added Approval guard on the Integration stage as shown below.

[image]

However the pipeline was running indefinitely and would never end. So I've set a 5 minute timeout on approval and now the Integration stage is marked as Skipped if nobody approves.

I feel I'm not doing it the right way as it is quite different from classic release.

Is this the correct way to handle release pipeline when using YAML ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this the correct way to handle release pipeline when using YAML ?

Yes, you are on the correct way (At least for now).

Just as you said in the question, Azure devops **does not** support manually triggered stage(s) in YAML multi-stage pipelines. So, we could not simply trigger manually the deployment stage we are interested in.

There is an **On Roadmap** user voice about this request:

[Manually triggered stage(s) in YAML multi-stage pipelines](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/697467/manually-triggered-stages-in-yaml-multi-stage-pipe.html)

You can look forward to it, and I believe it will meet us soon.

So, your workaround is correct for now.